# Efficient algorithms for finding the limit of a sub-sequence

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, real-numbers

Given a sequence $A_N={a_1,a_2,a_3...,a_N}$ of real numbers, and given that there exist some sub-sequence which generated from some deterministic converging  sequence.

Are there any efficient algorithms for finding the limit of the converging sub-sequence?

Comment: I assume you want these sub-sequences to be infinite? How do you restrict the problem to be *computable*? It's clearly not in this form (uncountably infinite in- and output domains). What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: How are the reals defined? How is the sequence defined? Your first version made a bit of sense as it was an infinite sequence, depending on how things were defined. But you are now considering a finite sequence, and convergence can only be trivial (from what limited knowledge I have of the topic) ... and I do not know what is a deterministic sequence.  Also I seem to recall that if a sequence converges to some value, any converging subsequence will converge on the same value.

Comment: What is the context of your question? Where does it come from? Is it from a course? Which? What theory are you learning? How do you define real number? Is it computable reals?

Comment: What do you mean by "converging sequence", when the sequence is finite?  What do you mean by a "*deterministic* converging sequence"?  What does it mean to be "generated from" such a sequence?  Please edit your question to define all terms, flesh out the problem, and explain more clearly what the algorithmic task is.  (You might also consider adding an example.)  Then, tell us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for a different version of the question; doubtless there will be other versions in the future. The version of the question this answer is targeted at had an infinite sequence $(a_i)$ of real numbers and a real number $L$ which is a *known* accumulation point of the sequence.

It really depends on your notion of computation, as Raphael comments, but the following idea is probably your best bet:

1. Identify a member $a_{i_0}$ within distance $1$ of $L$.
2. Identify a member $a_{i_1}$ within distance $1/2$ of $L$, where $i_1 > i_0$.
3. Identify a member $a_{i_2}$ within distance $1/4$ of $L$, where $i_2 > i_1$.
4. And so on.

Comment: Ok, I have change my question to avoid the problem in the input and output